# Flushing right in flalign but without &&

Tags: flalign

Hi im using flalign to get the two columns in my equation.
My problem is that i cant align the comments on the right.
I want them aligned to the right. If I use the double && the comment will be aligned right but it is way outside my margin. My code looks like this.

```
    \RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag} % Check for obsolete commands and packages and throw warning if such occur.
\documentclass[12pt%
]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{%
%   paper=letter,%
  twoside=false,%
  fontsize=10pt,%
  headinclude=true,%
  footinclude=true,%
  mpinclude=false,%
  index=totoc,%          Substitutes the obsolete option idxtotoc.
  %bibliography=totoc,  % Substitutes the obsolete option bibtotoc.
  numbers=noenddot%      Equivalent to the obsolete option pointlessnumbers.
}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}  
  \geometry{letterpaper,margin=1in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % 'nonfrechspacing' is on.
  \hyphenation{av-er-age av-er-aged con-verged con-verg-ing con-verg-es con-ver-gence con-ver-gen-ces de-note Di-ri-chlet ex-te-ri-or Helm-holtz Le-gen-dre Lip-schitz %
              per-me-a-bil-i-ty po-rous po-rous-ly Neu-mann non-po-rous un-po-rous re-sult swell-ing}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} % Provides \enquote.
\usepackage{enumitem}        % Improved itemize & enumerate environments.
  \setlist{noitemsep}        % Remove vertical space between items but leave space around whole list.
\usepackage{booktabs}        % Improve tabulars, enable \top-, \mid-, \bottomrule.
\usepackage{tabularx}        % Specify total length of tabular.
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcommand*{\tabemph}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % emphasize tabular headings

\usepackage{setspace}        % Provides \onehalfspacing.
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
  \newcommand{\emidx}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
  \newtheorem*{beweis}{Beweis}
  \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
  \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
  \newtheorem{model}{Model}
  \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
  \newtheorem{implementationnote}{Implementation note}
  \newtheorem{algorithmus}{Algorithm}
  \newtheorem{korollar}{Korollar}
  
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Bemerkung}
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{beispiel}{Beispiel}
  \newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}


%% Miscellaneous packages.
\usepackage{placeins} % Provides \FloatBarrier to force figures and tables to be printed before the barrier.
  
%% Manipulate par indents.
\newcommand*{\linebreakmagic}{\catcode`\^^M=10 }    % deactivates automatic par-break
\newcommand*{\linebreakunmagic}{\catcode`\^^M=5 }   % reactivates it
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}


%% My new commands
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\newcommand{\ui}{\{u_i\}}
\newcommand{\uil}{\{u_i\}_{i=1}^\infty}
\newcommand*{\iot}{\int_{\Omega_T}}  
\newcommand{\Lpc}{L^p_c \left(0,T;W^{1,p}(\Omega) \right)}
\newcommand{\Lp}{L^p \left(0,T;W^{1,p}(\Omega) \right)}
\newcommand*{\ot}{\Omega_T}  
\newcommand*{\LL}[1]{L^{#1}(\Omega_T)}
\newcommand*{\dt}{\partial_t}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bbm}
\newcommand{\intt}{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}}
\newcommand{\io}{\int_{\Omega}}
%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}


%% Commands.  
%\newcommand*{\overunderset}[3]{\overset{#1}{\underset{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand*{\eps}{\epsilon}    
\newcommand*{\E}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}{#1}}}              
\newcommand*{\setT}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{T}}}
\newcommand*{\setE}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand*{\setV}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{V}}}
\newcommand*{\vphi}{\varphi}                                     % Basis function.
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}

% Vector.
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}
  \newcommand*{\vecc}[1]{\mathbfsf{#1}}                          % Tensor or matrix.
\newcommand*{\normal}{\vec{n}}                                   % Outward unit normal.
\newcommand*{\laplace}{\upDelta}                                 % Laplace operator (this is NOT the same as \Delta which is used for a difference). 
\newcommand*{\grad}{\vec{\nabla}}                                % Gradient.
\newcommand*{\curl}{\vec{\nabla}\times}                          % Curl.
\renewcommand*{\div}{\vec{\nabla}\cdot}                          % Divergence.
% \newcommand*{\cdot}{\,\raisebox{0.41ex}{$\centerdot$}\,}
\newcommand*{\NDdiv}{\ND{\vec{\nabla}}\cdot}               % Dimensionless divergence.
\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}                                    % Differential d for ``int dx''.
\newcommand*{\abs}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right|}}                         % Absolute value or volume.
\renewcommand*{\L}{\mathcal{L}}                                  % Linear bounded mappings.
\newcommand*{\C}{\mathcal{C}} % continuous functions
\newcommand*{\D}{\mathcal{D}} % distributions
\newcommand*{\card}[1]{\ensuremath{\##1}}                        % Cardinality of a set.
\newcommand*{\cls}[1]{\overline{#1}}                                 % closure
\newcommand*{\transpose}[1]{{#1}^\mathrm{T}}                     % Transposition.
\newcommand*{\invtrans}[1]{{#1}^\mathrm{-T}}                     % Inversion/transposition.
\newcommand*{\jump}[1]{\left\llbracket{#1}\right\rrbracket}      % Jump of a discontinuous value.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\cond}{cond}                               % Condition number.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\conv}{conv}                               % Convex hull.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\diag}{diag}                               % Diagonal matrix.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\diam}{diam}                               % Diameter.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sign}{sign}                               % Sign.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supp}{supp}                               % Support.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\newcommand{\upwind}[1]{#1^{\uparrow}}                           % Upwind symbol. Alternatively, \newcommand{\upwind}[1]{\prescript{\uparrow}{}{#1}}   
\newcommand{\downwind}[1]{#1^{\downarrow}}                       % Downwind symbol. Alternatively, \newcommand{\downwind}[1]{\prescript{\downarrow}{}{#1}}       
\usepackage{upgreek}                                             % Greek letters in upright font.
\newcommand*{\muCT}{\mbox{$\upmu$CT}}                            % Abbreviation for micro-CT. 
\newcommand*{\llbrace}{\lbrace\hspace*{-0.235em}\vert}
\newcommand*{\rrbrace}{\vert\hspace*{-0.23em}\rbrace}
\newcommand*{\avg}[1]{\llbrace{#1}\rrbrace}                      % Average.
\newcommand*{\II}{I\!I}                                          % Roman numbers.
\newcommand*{\III}{I\!I\!I}
\newcommand*{\IV}{I\!V}
\newcommand*{\V}{V}
\newcommand*{\VI}{V\!I} 
\newcommand*{\VII}{V\!I\!I}
\newcommand*{\Gammah}{\Gamma_h}
\newcommand*{\GammaD}{\Gamma_\mathrm{D}}
\newcommand*{\GammaN}{\Gamma_\mathrm{N}}
%% Characteristic Numbers and Constants %%
\newcommand*{\Pe}{\mbox{Pe}}                                    % Peclet number.
\newcommand*{\tc}{{t_\mathrm{c}}}
\newcommand*{\Cn}{\mathrm{Cn}}                                  % Cahn number.
\renewcommand*{\Re}{\mathrm{Re}}                                % Reynods number (overwrites the fraktur-R).
\newcommand*{\Ca}{\mathrm{Ca}}                                  % Capillary number.
\newcommand*{\Fr}{\mathrm{Fr}}                                  % Froude number.
\newcommand*{\St}{\mathrm{St}}                                  % Strouhal number.
\newcommand*{\kB}{k_\mathrm{B}}                                 % Boltzmann constant.
\newcommand*{\NA}{N_\mathrm{A}}                                 % Avogadro constant.
\newcommand*{\hP}{h_\mathrm{P}}                                 % Planck constant.
\newcommand*{\Ncomp}{{N_\mathrm{comp}}}                         % Number of components.
\newcommand*{\Nc}{{N_\mathrm{c}}}                               % Number of components.
\newcommand*{\Nel}{{N_\mathrm{el}}}                             % Number of elements.
\newcommand*{\Nst}{{N_\mathrm{st}}}                             % Number of time steps.
\newcommand*{\Nloc}{{N_\mathrm{loc}}}                           % Number of local degrees of freedom.
\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathrel{+}=}                              % '+=' symbol.
\newcommand*{\form}[3]{\mathcal{#1}_h\big(#2,#3\big)}           % Forms in the variational formulations, e.g. \form{M}{u}{v}
\newcommand*{\strain}{{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}}
\newcommand*{\dual}[4]{{\left\langle#1\,,\,#2\right\rangle}_{#3,#4}} % duality pairing.
\newcommand*{\norm}[2]{\|#1\|_{#2}}                              % Norm.
\newcommand*{\seminorm}[2]{\vert#1\vert_{#2}}                    % Seminorm.
\newcommand*{\scalprod}[3]{{\left(#1\,,\,#2\right)}_{#3}}        % Scalar product.
\newcommand*{\Lscalprod}[2]{{\left(#1\,,\,#2\right)}}            % L2 scalar product (scaled).
\newcommand*{\brokennorm}[2]{|\!|\!|#1|\!|\!|_{#2}}              % Broken norm, e.g. \brokennorm{v}{H^0(\setE_h)}.
\newcommand*{\Lnorm}[1]{\|#1\|}                                  % L2 norm (not scaled).
\newcommand*{\xLnorm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}                      % L2 norm (scaled).
\newcommand*{\xnorm}[2]{\left\|#1\right\|_{#2}}                  % Norm (scalable).
\newcommand*{\on}[2]{\left.#1\right\vert_{#2}}                   % Restriction on a set, ie eg u|G.
\newcommand*{\CQ}[1]{{#1}_\mathrm{c}}                            % Characteristic quantity.
\newcommand*{\ND}[1]{\tilde{#1}}                                 % Nondimensionalized quantity.
\def\Xint#1{\mathchoice
{\,\XXint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
{\!\XXint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
{\XXint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
{\XXint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
\!\int}
\def\XXint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$ }
\vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$ }}\kern-.59\wd0}}
\def\ddashint{\Xint=}
\def\dashint{\Xint-}
%\newcommand*{\fint}{\;\dashint}                               % Mean value integral.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}                      % argmin.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minmod}{minmod}                        % minmod.


%% title and language
%\selectlanguage{american}

  
                      
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom % latex no longer streches vertical spaces s.th. text reaches the bottom
\onehalfspacing % increase vertical spacing between lines since 'newpxtext' font is too dense
\linebreakmagic
\allowdisplaybreaks
\selectlanguage{ngerman}







\begin{flalign*}
    &&R_1&\leq C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)}+C_7C_2\tilde{C}  
    \sqrt{Q_i -1} 
    \norm{\nabla u_i}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)}^{p_i-1} \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p_i}(\ot)}&&[\text{mit } (\ref{2.22}) ] \\

    &&&\leq  C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)}+ C_7
    C_2  \tilde{C}
    C^{p_i-1}_*\sqrt{Q_i -1}  \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p_i}(\ot)} &&[\text{o.B.d.A. } C_*\geq1] \\
    
    &&&\leq  C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)}+ C_7
    C_2  \tilde{C}
    C^{p_i}_*\sqrt{Q_i -1}  \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p_i}(\ot)} &&[\text{für $i$ groß genug gilt } p_i\leq p+\delta ] \\
    
     &&&\leq  C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)}+ C_7
    C_2  \tilde{C}
    C^{p+\delta}_*\sqrt{Q_i -1}  \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)} \\

    &&&\leq  \left(C_7^2\abs{p_i-p}+ C_7 C_2 \tilde{C} C^{p+\delta}_*\sqrt{Q_i -1} \right) \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)} \\
    &&&\leq C_8 \eps_i \norm{\nabla \phi}{L^{p+\delta}(\ot)}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, **(i)** make your document example a s MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small document which reproduce your problem. So far most of your preamble is not related to the problem. Please remove all what is not needed for your equation; **(ii)** your equation is to wide that can be fit on the page; **(iii)** for what you like to achieve, you not need `flalign`,  just `align` would be sufficient;  **(iv)** for the text on right side: try to insert them in `\tag` command.

Comment: unrelated, but you have set both parindent and parskip to opt which makes it hard to distinguish paragraphs (the `\linebreakmagic` command is also very odd and prevents blank lines denoting paragraphs)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll like it:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

As I mentioned in my comment:

- Please, (in the next questions) make your document example as an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which reproduce your problem.
- So far most of your preamble is not related to the your problem. You should remove from preamble all what is not needed for your equation.
- Your equation, as you write it, is to wide that can be fit on the page.
- For what you like to achieve, you not need `flalign`, just `align` would be sufficient. However, nicer result you will get, if you will move to the left border by use `fleqn` environment defined in the `nccmath` package.
- For the text on right side: try to insert them in `\tag*` command as I do in MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % for absolute
\newcommand*{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}       % for norm
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
R_1 & \leq  C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)}
            + C_7C_2\widetilde{C}\sqrt{Q_i -1}
            \norm{\nabla u_i}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)}^{p_i-1} 
            \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p_i}(\Omega_t)}
        \tag*{[mit (\ref{2.22})]}\\
%
    & \leq  C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)}
            + C_7 C_2 \widetilde{C} C^{p_i-1}_* \sqrt{Q_i-1}  
            \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p_i}(\Omega_t)}
        \tag*{[o.B.d.A. $C*\geq 1$]} \\
%
    & \leq  C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)}
            + C_7 C_2  \widetilde{C} C^{p_i}_*\sqrt{Q_i -1}  
            \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p_i}(\Omega_t)}
        \tag*{[für $i$ groß genug gilt $p_i\leq p+\delta$ ]} \\
%
     & \leq C_7^2 \abs{p_i-p} \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)}+ C_7
            C_2  \widetilde{C}
    C^{p+\delta}_*\sqrt{Q_i -1}  \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)} \\
%
    & \leq  \bigl(C_7^2\abs{p_i-p} + C_7 C_2 \tilde{C} C^{p+\delta}_*\sqrt{Q_i-1} \bigr) 
            \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)} \\
    & \leq  C_8 \epsilon_i \norm{\nabla\phi}_{L^{p+\delta}(\Omega_t)}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Mostly off-topic:

- Defining so many abbreviations is not smart idea. With them your code is for the most of other people unreadable or make them unnecessary troubles, if they like prepare it for publishing in some journal. As you can see, in my MWE is not used no one of them, also are corrected definition for `\abs` and `\norm`.
- In systems of equation had not be inserted empty lines (as you do), they causes errors.
- I was lost in declarations of document class, so I use `article` as document class.
- It is not recommended to use `tabu` package since it is buggy and not maintained. Good replacement are powerful packages `tabularray` and `nicematrix` (both wit a bit different syntax as is used in `tabu`).

Comment: Your way of coding it looks great. However i can't use fleqn at the moment. When i want to import nccmath. I get a ton of errors from amsmath. Commenting amsmath out doesnt work either :/

Comment: Do you test my MWE as it is? I'm convinced that source of your errors are your preamble. It is messy, bad organized with repetition of packages loading and incorrect order of loading. In the first you need clean-up it. A way, how to do this, is start with my MW, then replace `article` with document class which you use, than follows in the step by spet adding packages related for math (I doubt that other than used in my MWE is needed) in correct order (`nccmath` had to be after `mathtools`), remove `amsmath` (it is called by `mathtools)` etc. At each step compile document.

Comment: You have made my master thesis so much better. Thank you very much :)